# Failure in loading image from resources

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

I'm using SFML with C++ in VS2012. My program have a lot of images, but i'm stuck trying to load some of them from resource. I've successfully implemented the file in the projectname.rc and everything looks fine, but it's generating an exception when i'm trying to load the image, it says: "failed to load image from memory, no data provided" (this is from sfml).

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h" 

sf::Image LoadImageFromResource(const std::string& name)
{
    HRSRC rsrcData = FindResource(NULL, name.c_str(), RT_RCDATA);
    if (!rsrcData)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find resource.");

    DWORD rsrcDataSize = SizeofResource(NULL, rsrcData);
    if (rsrcDataSize <= 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Size of resource is 0.");

    HGLOBAL grsrcData = LoadResource(NULL, rsrcData);
    if (!grsrcData)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load resource.");

    LPVOID firstByte = LockResource(grsrcData);
    if (!firstByte)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to lock resource.");

    sf::Image image;
    if (!image.loadFromMemory(firstByte, rsrcDataSize))
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load image from memory.");

    return image;
}

int main()
{
sf::Image resource = LoadImageFromResource("IDB_BITMAP1");
// (...)
}
```

this is form my (projectname.rc) resource file:

```
#include "resource.h"
#include "afxres.h"

//(. . .)

IDB_BITMAP1      BITMAP     "C:\\ (...) \\sprite.bmp"
```

and from my resource.h:

```
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     107

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        108
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40003
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: if there was no exception before "image.loadFromMemory", then problem is in image itself. have you tried to load this bitmap from disk?

Comment: Oh wait, i found the problem! I was saving the resource as BITMAP type, while in the HRSRC i was saying it's RCDATA type. I've changed the resource to RCDATA and now it works fine. Sorry guys, lame question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that i've asked for RT_RCDATA type at HRSRC and was trying to pass an BITMAP resource type. I've changed the

```
IDB_BITMAP1      BITMAP     "C:\\ (...) \\sprite.bmp"
```

to:

```
IDB_BITMAP1      RCDATA     "C:\\ (...) \\sprite.bmp"`
```

Now it works fine.